# What is the recommended metastore for hive?

Tags: hive

In big data frameworks like Cloudera and Hortonworks, I've read that the default metastore for hive is mysql. Although they give support for other rdbms types like postgresql, oracle, derby. I'd like to know what is the best recommended rdbms to use for hive metastore and why?

Comment: kindly refer this link for using different rdbms for metastore http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-2-0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html

Comment: It just say recommended is mysql because it's common and well tested. Other reasons aside from that?